# transform: rotateZ overriding CSS positioning during animation

Tags: html, css

I have an issue using `transform` `rotateZ` on a website.

I am attempting to rotate a square that has two elements laid on top of it. The rotation is activated by a click button.

Before the button is clicked, the square is positioned correctly behind the two elements.

However, once I click the button to execute the animation, the square is brought to the top. Upon completing the animation, it returns to its original position below the mentioned elements.

I have tried changing the `z-index` of the elements to make them stay above but that doesn't seem to work.

Below is my code. Does anyone have any idea what is happening here?

```css
.squareMask1 {

  width: 230px;
  height: 210px;
  line-height: 210px;
  background-color: red;

  margin-top: -155px;
  margin-left: 60px;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 2s;

}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% { transform:rotateZ(0deg)}

  50% { }

  100% { transform:rotateZ(-180deg)}   
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <a href="" class="circle">
    <!-- Changed all this stuff -->

    <span class="icon_humans dataicon"></span>
    <h4>Human <br> Demographics</h4>
    <div id="squareButton"></div>

  </a>
</div>
```

```
$('.icon_humans').click(function() {
    $('.circle').addClass('circle1');
    $('#squareMask').addClass('squareMask1');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.circle').removeClass('circle1');
        $('#squareMask').removeClass('squareMask1');

    }, 5500);
});
```

Comment: Why do you use some prefixed properties and some standard ones? Which is the code that activates the animation?

Comment: I don't think all your code is there. I don't see a `#squareMask` div or element.